# How do I remove LaTeX code that I will not use (e.g., typesetting Japanese)?

Tags: texlive, tlmgr, russian, japanese

I have a full installation of TeXlive but currently the space on my computer is very limited (don't ask why but Windows has something to do with it). I use Ubuntu as my OS.

I am trying to increase the available space by deleting stuff (old documents, photos replicated on thumb drives, etc.) that is no longer valuable. I expect never to have to use LaTeX to typeset, for example, Japanese (and probably Russian and other non-European scripts). I use `tlmgr` for updates. How can I deleted the Japanese-related code from my TeXlive installation?

Answer (score 2):

As said in the other answers, one can make a partial installation of TeX live using Debian packages (maybe outdated) or the vanilla distribution, but a third way could be use MikTeX, traditional Windows distro, but that now can be used [also in Linux](https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex-unx) and I guess that by default make only  a basic installation as usual in Windows.

Other option is [TinyTeX](https://yihui.org/tinytex/), that is a basic TeX Live install plus a few common packages, of only about 61Mb on macOS/Linux, and 94Mb on Windows, and of course,  you can install later the LaTeX packages that you actually need.

I recommend this to live in the R-LaTeX ecosystem. I mean using Rstudio as landscape and R many packages related with LaTeX -- knitr, rmarkdown, bookdown, RefManageR,xtable, etc. --- as fauna of the habitat, because then install TinyTeX is just install the R package `tinytex`, that beside the installation of the LaTeX distro,  also add functions to compile LaTeX from R (e.g., `tinytex::pdflatex('test.tex')` and then, if `test.tex` need some missing packages, they will be installed through `tlmgr` automatically.

However, note that using RStudio or R is not a mandatory requirement, and you can install and use TinyTeX alone.

Answer (score 1):

If your full version of TeX Live was installed by a package manager, you can select a more minimal set of packages and remove the full one.

If you have a custom installation, you can run `tlshell` or `tlmgr --gui` to manually remove packages.  You can also remove packages manually with `tlmgr remove`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Ubuntu, there is no need to install `texlive` "manually", just use your package manager.

`texlive` in Ubuntu comes divided over multiple packages, see e.g.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=texlive&searchon=names&suite=focal&section=all

If you need to save space, most probably all you need is `texlive-base`. Then, you can add some selected packages (e.g., extra fonts), when and if you need them.

For a reasonably broad selection of `texlive` packages, try `texlive`

If you need the full `texlive` distribution, `texlive-full` is your choice